# Prove that $x_{n+1}=a-\frac{1}{x_n}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

**Problem:** Prove that, $x_{n+1}=a-\frac{1}{x_n}$ is convergent for $a\ge 4$ where $x_0=a$

**My progress:** The only technique I know to show a sequence convergent, is through Monotone convergent theorem. So I tried to show that the sequence is bounded, but messed up. (I tried it by induction). Not I can show that it is Monotone (and the sequence doesn't seem to be monotone).
Please help me. If it is posted before I am unaware of that (I searched it but couldn't find). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Side note:  "The only technique I know to show a sequence convergent, is through Monotone convergent theorem".  better learn some others.  if the only car repair you know is replacing a fan belt it's not going to help you if you get a flat tire.  (Although it this case the monotone covergent theorem *is* the way to go.)

Comment: @fleablood Instead of criticizing someone for their ignorance, how about actually suggest a few alternative tests by name and citation, so that OP can look it up.

Comment: Yes @fleablood If you please tell me the name of the techniques (or link to some good resources to learn them), it will be helpful for me .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bounded:**

Base case: $x_0=a\geq 3$.

Inductive proof: if $x_n\geq 3$ holds true for $n=k$, then for $n=k+1$:

$x_k\geq 3\Longrightarrow -\frac{1}{x_k}\geq -\frac{1}3\Longrightarrow x_{k+1}=a-\frac{1}{x_k}\geq a-\frac{1}3\geq 4-\frac{1}3\geq 3$.

By induction we proved that $x_n\geq3$ holds true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In other words, the sequence is bounded.

**Monotony:**

Base case: $x_1=a-\frac{1}a<x_0=a$.

Inductive proof: if $x_{n+1}<x_n$ holds true for $n=k$, then for $n=k+1$:

$x_{k+1}<x_k\Longrightarrow -\frac{1}{x_{k+1}}<-\frac{1}{x_k}\Longrightarrow a-\frac{1}{x_{k+1}}<a-\frac{1}{x_k}\Longrightarrow x_{k+2}<x_{k+1}$.

By induction we proved that the sequence $x_n$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: This is correct, +1. However, the bounded below by $3$ proof should come first. In the monotony proof, you assumed $x_n>0$.

Comment: @zugzug Yes you're right. I will edit my answer.